# PopupMenu in Table

Tags: popup

The code `PopupMenu[Dynamic@x, {a, b, c}]` yields a popup menu, and choosing an item stores its value in `x`.

I'd like to do this (say) three times, in a table, so that the results are stored in three variables called `Subscript[x,i]`, where `i` is the table counter. Something like:

`Table[PopupMenu[Dynamic@Subscript[x, i], {a, b, c}], {i, 3}]`

So, if someone picked `c` from the second popup in the resulting list, then `Subscript[x,2]` would now have the value `c`, but the others would remain unchanged.

The above code ignores the subscripted variable, and all three popups take on the same value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use With:

```
Table[PopupMenu[With[{i = i}, Dynamic@Subscript[x, i]], {a, b, c}], {i, 3}]
```